# Regarding isolation between conda environments

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip, anaconda, development-environment

I have a conda environment `M` in which I had installed `scikit-learn`. I had done this installation by going to the local scikit repository at path "D" (where D is `data/retry_runs/repo_testbed_dir/scikit-learn__scikit-learn__0.22__14706`) in my machine and had then run `pip install -e .`.

Now, when I am installing a new conda environment named `N`, the `scikit-learn` being used in `N` is the one at path `D`. I have verified this by running `pip list` in environment `N` and here is the output:

```
scikit-learn              0.22.dev0            <Directory D's absolute path>
```

I am making some unrelated changes in directory D for a different task and do not want it to interfere with the task I am performing using environment `N`. As a result, I want the scikit-learn installation in environment `N` to **NOT** use the one already locally available at directory `D` but to use the **unmodified version** of `scikit-learn` mentioned in the `requirements.txt` of environment `N`.

**How can I achieve this ? (I want to achieve the same not just for scikit-learn but also for all the dependencies mentioned in the `requirements.txt`)**

Here are some additional details about my system:

```bash
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```